# Running different query base on resource parent

Tags: pyramid, traversal

I'm working on a pyramid traversal project and i want to run different query for retrieving the same resource base on its parent or so.
Say i have 3 resources: Customer, Store, Order. now both Customer and Store could have a list of Orders. So i define an OrderListResource as a resource and my view is like:

```
@view_config(context=resources.OrderListResource, renderer='json')
    def view_order_list(context, request):
        return {orders: context.retrieve_method()}
```

Now i wonder what is the best practice to retrieve data base on resource parent?
For example how OrderListResource should decide to retrieve orders by customer id or by store id. the logics should lie on the view or the resource itself?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you're using traversal, getting to the parent of your resource is very easy:

```
parent = context.__parent__

query = session.query(OrderList)

if isinstance(parent, CustomerResource):
   query = query.filter(OrderList.customer_id == parent.id)
elif isinstance(parent, StoreResource):
   query = query.filter(OrderList.store_id == parent.id)
```

If the parent you want to check may not be an immediate parent of your resource you can use [pyramid.traversal.find_interface](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/docs/pyramid/en/latest/api/traversal.html#pyramid.traversal.find_interface) method.

Alternatively, if the logic differs a lot depending on whether the Order is contained within a Customer or Store, you may have two separate views using the `containment` view predicate.

```
@view_config(context=resources.OrderListResource, containment=CustomerResource, renderer='json')
def view_order_list_for_customer(context, request):
    return ...

@view_config(context=resources.OrderListResource, containment=StoreResource, renderer='json')
def view_order_list_for_store(context, request):
    return ...
```

Comment: I never had any idea about **containment**. i will check it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that every resource in a resource tree has an identity then what is the purpose and the identity of a resource called `OrderListResource`?
To match a resource as a context during traversal it has to be created previously. Do you want to update these resources while doing CRUD operations on your real resources??? That is why I understand your idea behind `OrderListResource` as a collection of Order resources as a result of a dynamic query at application runtime.

You want to store customers, stores and orders. Every customer, store and order has an identity that enables you to find the item in a collection. You could create such a resource tree.

```
root (/)                   (Root Resource)
|- customers               (Container supporting traversal)
|- stores                  (Container supporting traversal)
|- orders                  (Container supporting traversal)
```

URL patterns to traverse the resource tree

```
/customers/{uid}
/stores/{uid}
/orders/{uid}
```

Given that you save the relation to `store` and `customer` in an `order` resource, how to query the relationship between your resources with a natural URL pattern that fits well into the existing URL patterns?

```
/customers/{uid}/orders
/stores/{uid}/orders
```

Find orders from a single customer

```
@view_config(name='orders', context=resources.Customer, renderer='json')
def view_order_list_for_customer(context, request):
    customer = context.__name__
    orders = request.root['orders']
    orders_by_customer = [order for order in orders if order.customer == customer]

    return dict(orders = orders_by_customer)
```

Find orders from a single store

```
@view_config(name='orders', context=resources.Store, renderer='json')
def view_order_list_for_store(context, request):
    store = context.__name__
    orders = request.root['orders']
    orders_by_store = [order for order in orders if order.store == store]

    return dict(orders = orders_by_store)
```

These views are [location-aware](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/resources.html#location-aware-resources) and enable you to create the query with information from the given context.

Please notice that the view name matches the name of the resource containing all `Order` resources.

To explore the relationship between two resources your URLs would look usually like

```
/resource/identifier/resource
```

Comment: Yeah, i totally forgot about view name. but afaik view name must be the last part of the url, right?  
if so how could **customers/{uid}/orders/{uid}** works?

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of that URL. please explain. Remember details about 'context', 'view name' and 'subpath' -- http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/traversal.html#a-description-of-the-traversal-algorithm

Comment: Ok. i was mixing up your way with mine! anyway the problem is that i already have a 'orders' key in my customer and store resources. so view name couldn't help much. i think it is more logical to go with **containment** keyword in view definition or simply check if type(context.parent) == customer ... . Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: This information definitely should have been part of your question. An 'orders' key goes for exploring the relationship in model code, but you asked for exploring it in view code. May be I should have asked for more context and details. Anyway I do not see any value in inventing an OrderListResource and since Order is related to Customer AND Store there is no clear parent/child relationship. I would like to see another question from you on SO discussing your domain model.

Comment: Why OrderListResource? well there is a one-to-many relation from customer to order and from store to order, so in CustomerResource __getitem__ if key equals with 'orders' a OrderListResource will be returned without any db query done. because **i don't want populate all orders before i really need them.** like this url:/customers/c_id/orders/o_id i just want to get one specific order(o_id). so in __getitem__ of OrderListResource the query will be done and it'll return the specified OrderResource.[SEE](http://ilogue.com/jasper/blog/pyramid-traversal--wrap-your-model-with-a-resource-adapter)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in your direction. Interesting blog post. But only small snippets, no pro and cons. Never came across such a pyramid model anyway. Good luck :-)